# Adding class list to combobox

Tags: c#, list, class, combobox

I'm making a list of groupnames which the user writes down in a textbox. After checking whether the groupname already exists, it adds it to the list.
I'm trying to add the objects to this list:

```
List<Group> Groups = new List<Group>();
```

The problem I'm having is that I keep getting the error:
*An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll*

This happens due to the line of code that is supposed to add the groupnames in the combobox:

```
cbxGroups.DataSource = Groups.ToString();
```

This is what the class that the list is based on looks like:

```
class Group
{
    //Fields
    private string nameGroup;


    //Properties
    public string NameGroup
    {
        get { return this.nameGroup; }
        set { nameGroup = NameGroup; }
    }



    //Constructor
    public Groep(string name)
    {
        this.nameGroup = name;

    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to solve this and I was hoping I could find some answers here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Linq` `Select` method to get collection of group names.

```
cbxGroups.DataSource = Groups.Select(g => g.NaamGroep).ToList();
```

`ToString()` implementation of `List` returns it's type in string form, not items.